# Adding a UITextview as a toolbar item

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

I am creating a messaging app for iPhone.
I want the user to have the capability of entering a newline while pressing return.
But I am having trouble putting a UITextview inside the toolbar item.
I have seen the same with UITextView.
When return key is pressed i want to get the new line in UITextField.Is this possible.[image]

Please help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What trouble you are having in your way ?. please be specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't add it using IB but you can do it programmatically. You will need to set its `contentInset` so that the text content is not pushed up on editing because the content will become invisible due to the text view's constrained size. I have added that in the example code below.

#### Example Code

```
UITextView * textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 32)] autorelease];
textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
UIBarButtonItem * barItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:textView] autorelease];

self.toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:barItem];
```